# ASP.Net page redirection doubt

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, redirect

I'm kinda new to ASP.NET and I have much more experience with windows forms.
I need to show a table with some result data in a page
Now, with winforms I would do something like this

```
ResultForm myForm = new ResultForm();

myForm.ResultDataTable = dataTable;

myForm.Show();
```

Any tip on how could I do something similar with Asp.Net?

tks

Comment: Maybe you should read a good book on the subject first...

Comment: I agree - even look through the tutorials on asp.net - this is in all the basic run throughs.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to a page using [**Server.Transfer**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800.aspx) method and in that page use a databound control. You can databind any data controls in ASP.Net, like gridview, datalist etc.

Set the datasource and then databind the control.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the DataGrid ASP.NET control:

In the *.ASPX* file

```
<asp:DataGrid runat="server" id="dgData" AutoGenerateColumns="true" />
```

In the *.ASPX.CS* file

```
dgData.DataSource = dataTable;
dgDate.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that you did work well for "windows-forms", but does not work in ASP.NET.
My suggestion, as well as other users too, is that you study a little about web development.

There are huge differences between "web-forms" and "windows-forms", starting with the types of objects and their behavior in the UI.

This code can not be applied to "web-forms" directly.